# Derivative of the Frobenius norm of an exponential function using chain rule

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-exponential

Let $G=\text{exp}(\sum_{k=1}^{6}a_{k}E_{k})$,
where $E_{k}$ is a constant square matrix, scalars  $\{a_{k}\}_{k=1,...6}$ is the coefficients of matrix $E_{k}$.

Let $\phi= \parallel G \parallel^{2}_{F}$.

My question is, how to calculate the derivative $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial a_{k}}$?

I use chain rule to calculate it, and have $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial a_{k}}=2\text{trace}(G^{T}E_{k})$. I don't know if it is correct?

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

For typing convenience let $\,X=\sum_k a_kE_k$

The block triangular method of Kenney & Laub says that
$${\rm G}\Bigg(\begin{bmatrix}X&E_k\\0&X\end{bmatrix}\Bigg) =  \begin{bmatrix}G&L_k\\0&G\end{bmatrix} $$
where $G = {\rm G}(X)\,\,\,$ 
and $$L_k = \lim_{h\rightarrow\,0}\, \frac{{\rm G}(X+hE_k)-{\rm G}(X)}{h}$$
For the current problem the function is: $\,\,{\rm G}(X) = \exp(X)$

Incrementing coefficient $a_k$ by $da_k\,$ will increment $(X,G)$ by the following amounts
$$\eqalign{
dX&=E_k\,da_k\cr dG &= L_k\,da_k
}$$ [**NB:** Your question assumes that $L_k=E_k$, but that assumption is false.]

Now consider how the Frobenius norm will be affected. 
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= \|G\|^2_F = G:G \cr
d\phi &= 2G:dG = 2G:L_k\,da_k \cr
\frac{d\phi}{da_k} &= 2G:L_k = 2\,{\rm tr\,}(G^TL_k) \cr
}$$
where a colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product; an alternate notation for the trace function $$A:B = {\rm tr\,}(A^TB)$$
While this is not a closed-form solution, as long as you are able to evaluate the function of interest on a block triangular argument, you can calculate the required derivative.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can the solution be written as  $d\phi= 2G:L_{k}da_{k}=2L_{k}^{T}G:da_{k}$ then $\frac{d\phi}{da_{k}}=2L_{k}^{T}G$. If not, why?

Comment: No, you cannot write it that way because the dimensions of the LHS don't match the dimensions of the RHS, i.e. $\,(\phi, a_k, \frac{d\phi}{da_k})$ are scalars, whereas $L_k^TG$ is a matrix.

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful!